# In first-order ODE, can two integral curves be adjacent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I learn that two integral curves cannot cross each other,

because if so, the slope of the cross point is not determined.

Then can two integral curves be adjacent?

If not, please explain to me.

Comment: Two integral curves can cross for a case where we have no unique solution.

Comment: @MrYouMath Thank you so much!